# В чем смысл класса Permission в java

Tags: java, безопасность

```
public class Worker {

private static String path;

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    path = "C:\\glassfish-4.1.1\\glassfish4\\README.txt";
    Permission permission = new FilePermission(path, "read");
    try {
        AccessController.checkPermission(permission);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.printf(String.valueOf(e));
    }
    System.out.println(new FileInputStream(new File(path)).read());
}
}
```

Этот класс вернет что-то похожее на

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish4\README.txt" "read")84

Почему удалось прочитать из файла, когда прав на это нет!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для ограничения доступа к файлам в файловой системе используются методы класса [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

- `setExecutable()`
- `setReadable()`
- `setWritable()`

Пример, который приводите вы, относится к настройке `SecurityManager`. Это механизм который позволяет ограничивать Java приложению доступ к определенным ресурсам (не только файлам). В качестве примера, возьмем апплеты - `SecurityManager` не дает им доступа к файловой системе.

Почувствуйте разницу - `SecurityManager` **не модифицирует права файла** в файловой системе, а **запрещает Java приложению** совершать с ним определенные действия. В этом и смысл класса `Permission`, и наследуемых от него классов - они **описывают** эти действия.

Файл у вас прочитался потому что **в JDK**, по умолчанию, `SecurityManager` отключен. Проверить это можно таким образом:

```
System.out.println(System.getSecurityManager()); // null, если отключен
```

Запустите приложение с ключом VM `-Djava.security.manager` и файл у вас прочитать не получится, до тех пор пока не будет настроена соответствующая [security policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html). Дефолтные лежат в `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println(System.getSecurityManager());
        String path = "D:/test/file.txt";
        check(path, "read,write");
        System.out.println(new FileInputStream(new File(path)).read());
    }

    static void check(String path, String actions) {
        FilePermission perm = new FilePermission(path, actions);

        try {
            AccessController.checkPermission(perm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Подробнее смотрите в [официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html).